# ¿Como eliminar una Libreria que me esta cambiando el valor que les asigno a los id?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy seguro que es una lireria(pero no se cual es tengo muchas que no estoy usando y cuando ingrese lo de las tablas esas se activo) que me esta cambiando el valor asignado a los id y los remplaza por esto contentBody por ejemplo si mi id era asi

```
id="Enterate" //Lo cambia a // id="contentBody_Enterate"
```

En mi codigo si me aparece como lo estoy asignando pero cuando ejecuto la pagina y veo que no se ejecutan las funciones que le asigne a el id inspecciono el campo donde esta el id y aparece ese cambio, todo paso desde que meti una lineas de codigo que traian unas tablas desde ese momento comenzaron los problemas con ese **contentBody**

Comment: -Estas usando controles de asp.net ? como sera el <asp:Textbox> o similares. 
-Que es contentBody ? es un Panel de asp.net. 
-A que funciones haces referencia? es codigo javascript

Answer (score 0):

Si usas controles de `asp.net` y los ubicas dentro un Panel es el propio asp.net quien cambia los `Id`

Pero existe una propiedad que podria ayudar, pero solo aplica si usas `asp.net 4` versiones anteriores no disponen de esta propiedad

[Control.ClientIDMode Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode?view=netframework-4.0)

entonce debes definir `ClientIDMode="Static"`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

[ASP.NET 4.0 Web Control ClientID](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/709/aspnet-web-control-clientid)

Comment: <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="Imgbase64d" /> como seria en este caso ?

Comment: usa el <asp:Hidden>